# jQuery UI Accordion Control

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jQuery UI Accordion, where a number of checkboxes in each accordion section.

1- I want the accordion to start all collapsed, and all enabled.

2- When the user clicks on any checkbox, the accordion becomes disabled so the user can continue to check only the checkboxes within that group.

No, what's the name of the option to add to start all collapsed? My script is like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion" ).accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        animate: 1,
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

And what's the action to trigger to make the accordion disabled?

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkbox', function(event) {
    var check = $(this);
    var len = $('.checkbox:checked').length;
    if (check.is(':checked')) {
        $('#accordion').MAKE_IT_DISABLED;
    } else {
        if (len == 0) {
            $('#accordion').MAKE_IT_ENABLED;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you have a ready-made answer:

```
$("#accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

Collapsible means that you can collapse the panel with the current focus, and setting active to false means that none are active.

While it's possible to work with the CSS opacity attribute, the simpler way to do it is to add the appropriate class to the item.  You can disable the entire accordion by setting the disabled option to true, but you only want to disable the panels that you aren't in.  To disable a single panel:

```
$('#accordion #myH3').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

where `myH3` is the id of the particular `H3` header element you want to disable.  I'll leave you to work out the logic of determining which elements aren't the currently active one.

By the way, the `ui-state-disabled` class reduces the opacity of the element to .35.  Also, if you have things like buttons in your header panel, keep in mind that they will not be disabled if you disable the header.  And, if you specifically disable them, their opacity will be reduced by .35*.35, or to .1225 which is very faint.  If you want to keep the opacity of contained items consistent with the container when you disable the container, add a class to the contained items and use CSS to set the opacity to 1.

Answer (score 2):

For your second question, you can toggle a class called disabled for example:

```
.disabled {
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    opacity: .3;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

and I'm guessing you can use css for your first question, using `display: none` or `display: block`

Comment: Better IMHO to simply add the existing `ui-state-disabled` class, as jquery ui does to any disabled widget element. That way, your CSS is consistent with whatever CSS jquery ui applies to it.  No sense reinventing the wheel.  :)

Comment: @BobRodes I agree to a certain extent. I prefer not using any large jQuery libraries for simple stuff like an accordion. If you do use jQuery UI of course you can use this but it comes down to the same thing really. A small snippet of jQuery and some css will be enough and I'm guessing this answer could be useful for other people too, not having to rely on jQuery UI...

Comment: I'm with you to a certain extent as well.  I don't mean to suggest that your answer isn't useful, especially to someone who isn't using the whole framework.  I'm just saying that there's no need to create functionality that's already there, partly as a matter of principle.  Part of the reason to use the existing class is that it's consistent across the framework.  If the OP decided to disable the entire accordion using the `disabled` option, the opacity would vary by .05 from from when he added your `disable` class.  Tiny, I know, but the artist within quails.  :)